# Use new project to replace old app in Xcode/iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app I created years ago I want to update. The old version uses xib files and objective-c. I want to create a new version using swift and storyboards. Should I start over with a new project? It seems like I will be creating a mess trying to add storyboards and changing the language of the existing project. if I start over with a new project how do I make sure it replaces the old one in the App Store?

Comment: Yes, start new, you can make sure it will replace the old one by setting the bundle identifier to be the same as your old app, as long as you sign it with the same certificate.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure it replaces, you need to make sure that the BundleID is the same as the old one and all the provisioning profiles are the same.

I would suggest doing the following:

```
 1. make a copy of the old app and put it in a different folder far away from the project.
 2. delete all the source files and xibs and stuff in the project
 3. start writing.
```

The settings should remain the same, so the app will remain the same, app store wise.

Comment: What do you suggest to do, to preserver persistent data stored in CoreData? I made a copy of the old app, made sure to use same BundleID but I don't see old data anymore.

Comment: there is a folder that contains the coredata schemes and static dbs, you could copy that and not delete it